# Scrollable PDF in Rails - ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails website where the a user can upload a paper and another user can review/read it.
I used ActiveStorage to save the PDF.

Thanks to ActiveStorage, a user can preview the PDF (showing the first page), open it in another browser tab and download it.

HOWEVER I would like the user to be able to scroll through the PDF (since each PDF is longer than I page). The Preview does not allow me to do so because it displays only the first page.

In my `show.html.etb` I have these two link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Open the paper", @paper.paper_pdf, target: :_blank, :class => "btn btn-warning" %>
<%= link_to image_tag(@paper.paper_pdf.preview(resize: "1000x1000")), @paper.paper_pdf, target: :_blank %>
<%= link_to "Download the PDF", rails_blob_path(@paper.paper_pdf, disposition: :attachment), :class => "btn btn-success" %>
```

What do you suggest to use to display the paper and make it scrollable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using `iframe`.

```
<iframe src=<%= url_for(@paper.paper_pdf) %>
 width="700" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

With `<%= url_for(@paper.paper_pdf) %>` I get the URL of where my PDF is stored. It works on localhost, not sure if it works on a real server.